# MVC TextBoxFor display date format instead of value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, date-format

I’m working on ASP.NET application, and I have an issue with date formatting.
TextBoxFor is displaying Date Format instead of date.

**Regional Settings:**

United Kingdom, date format: “yyyy-mm-dd”.

**.NET Globalization - IIS Settings:**

```
Culture:                       Invariant Language (Invariant Country)
Enable Client Based Culture:   false
UI Culture:                    Invariant Language (Invariant Country)
File:                          Windows-1252
Requests:                      utf-8
Response Headers:              utf-8
Responses:                     utf-8
```

**MainView** (I have tried `ToShortDateString()` and `ToString("d")`)  :

```
<td>
    @item.InvoiceDate.ToShortDateString()
</td>
<td>
    @item.DueDate.ToString("d")
</td>
```

**Edit View:**

```
<div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-md-10">
             @Html.Label("Invoice Date:")
             <div class="fiveSpace"></div>
             @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.InvoiceDate, "{0:d}", new { type = "date" })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InvoiceDate)
       </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-md-10">
             @Html.Label("Due Date:")
             <div class="fiveSpace"></div>
             @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DueDate, "{0:d}", new { type = "date" })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DueDate)
       </div>
</div>
```

**Model:**

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Invoice Date.")]
public DateTime? InvoiceDate { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Due Date.")]
public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
```

**And result:**
[Table row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atAvT.png)

**Once I try to edit dates:**
[Date and Inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fomNS.png)

Correct value is stored in "value" but TextBoxFor displays date format. Also, when I have changed regional setting to other country, in MainView I **always** received dates in format "dd/mm/yyyy" and in edit view dates were displayed with **US format**, "mm/dd/yyyy".

I have tried:

- set up `<globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />` in `web.config`
- add `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}"]` to model

Is the problem on my side, or IIS?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.

I've replaced mentioned `TextBoxFor` with:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.InvoiceDate, new { @type = "date", @Value = Model.InvoiceDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") })
```

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The `TextBoxFor` with `type="date"` converts it to the `<input type="date">` HTML tag which doesn't support date format customization according to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date).

It can be achieved by some 3rd-party JS libraries like [Masked Input Plugin for jQuery](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput) or [datetime-input web component](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@fooloomanzoo/datetime-input)